# Javascript using map not giving required output as it is not grouping them

Tags: javascript

I have a list called 'series' which has all the data inside it. I am parsing in 'periodList' another string list and looping through this periodList list and using .filter to filter the main dataset (series). This is returning correctly. I am now trying to add items to the object myArray using .map but its not giving me my expected outcome.

I have attempted the below:

```
function chartBuilder(series, periodList) {

    var myArray = {}; //creates **a new empty object**

    for (var i in periodList) {


        var seriessplit = series.filter(function (type) {
            return type.pc === periodList[i];
        });



        myArray = seriessplit.map(elem => (
            {
                name: elem.pc,
                type: chartType,
                data: [elem.mid]
            }
        ));


        console.log(myArray);

    }
}
```

This currently gives me an output :

```
Array(7)
0: {name: "Oct 20", type: "Line", data: Array(1)}
1: {name: "Oct 20", type: "Line", data: Array(1)}
2: {name: "Oct 20", type: "Line", data: Array(1)}
3: {name: "Oct 20", type: "Line", data: Array(1)}
4: {name: "Oct 20", type: "Line", data: Array(1)}
5: {name: "Oct 20", type: "Line", data: Array(1)}
6: {name: "Oct 20", type: "Line", data: Array(1)}
```

But what I was expecting is for the data to be combined to look like the below:

```
  {
        name: "Oct 20",
        type: "Line",
        data: [45,45,24,25,64,65,87]
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? Seems to be creating a new item in the object for each new data value

Comment: Map iterates over each element of the array and returns an array of the same length, so you are declaring `myArray` as an empty object, and then reassigning it as the return value of `map()` which is an array of the length of `seriessplit`. Does `series split` contain the data array `[45,45,24,25,64,65,87]`?

Comment: It's a little bit confusing to name an object `myArray`

Comment: What is the problem? The content of `data` in the resulting array? What does "to look like" exactly mean? content? format of printing? Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. **specific input** (apart from just output)

Comment: To combine multiple array elements into a single object, it would be reccomended to use `Array.reduce`, not `Array.map`. would you share as example for the inputs (series, periodList)?

Comment: @pilchard split series contains the data. Split series is just a filtered array of the main data set.

Comment: @noamgaash series is a huge array list of data. E.g Mid, Name, Date, pc which is a code. period list is : Oct 20, Nov 20, Dec 20

Comment: @noamgaash thanks I can take a look at array.reduce

Comment: you'll need to provide a sample of what `seriessplit` looks like, it seems to be an array of objects? I'm guessing you need something along the line of `myArray = {name: splitseries[0].pc, type: chartType, data: seriessplit.map(({mid})=>mid)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to map only `data` not the whole array/object:

```js
const series = [
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 45},
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 45},
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 24},
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 25},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 145},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 145},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 124},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 125}
];
const chartType = "Line";

function chartBuilder(series, periodList) {
    for (let i in periodList) {
        const seriessplit = series.filter(({pc}) => pc === periodList[i]);

        const myArray = {
            name: periodList[i],
            type: chartType,
            data: seriessplit.map(({mid}) => mid)
        };

        console.log(myArray);
    }
}

chartBuilder(series, ["Oct 20", "Oct 21"]);
```

If you need an array of this you can map twice:

```js
const series = [
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 45},
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 45},
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 24},
    {pc: "Oct 20", mid: 25},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 145},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 145},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 124},
    {pc: "Oct 21", mid: 125}
];
const chartType = "Line";

function chartBuilder(series, periodList) {
    return periodList.map(period => {
        const seriessplit = series.filter(({pc}) => pc === period);

        const myArray = {
            name: period,
            type: chartType,
            data: seriessplit.map(({mid}) => mid)
        };

        console.log(myArray);
        return myArray;
    });
}

console.log(chartBuilder(series, ["Oct 20", "Oct 21"]));
```